# Is there a bug in the setting padding of a Button in 4.0 devices?

Tags: android, button, padding

I have a button in my layout with a bottom padding and it works properly on 5.0.2. But when I try it on 4.0 devices it does not respect the paddings I set. I have tried searching on the Internet but nothing points me to the root cause and a solution. Has anybody else encountered this?

Comment: Post your layout code here!

Comment: I don't think that there is a bug, show us how you are setting the padding.